# Improving multi-and query

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

```
SELECT wposts.*, wpostmeta.* 
FROM wp_posts wposts, wp_postmeta wpostmeta, wp_postmeta wpostmeta2, wp_postmeta wpostmeta3 
WHERE 
      wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
  AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta2.post_id 
  AND wposts.ID = wpostmeta3.post_id 
  AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'listing_subtype' 
  AND wpostmeta.meta_value = 'Seattle' 
  AND wpostmeta2.meta_key = 'district' 
  AND wpostmeta2.meta_value = 'Breadview' 
  AND wpostmeta3.meta_key = 'price_current' 
  AND wpostmeta3.meta_value BETWEEN 0 AND 800000
  AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
  AND wposts.post_type = 'vreb_property' 
ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20
```

I'm looking at this query now and thinking that I should probably improve upon it's efficiency. And I've been experimenting with so many variations, that I think it would be best to ask for SO input.

Comment: Well, without knowing, what this is all about I fear: The only way to optimize this is to ask yourself "Do I really need all this?" Additional: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` helps :)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Why do you want the `1/2/3` in different columns?

Comment: I'm looking at this query ...and thinking wouldn't it be great if the poster had included an explanation of intent.

Comment: Sorry, but I honestly feel that explaining "intent" is an absolute waste of time. It's clear what this query is attempting to do. There is nothing "wrong" with this query, other that it's efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do this with a `group by` and `having` clause.  To get the lists of posts:

```
select p.id
from wp_post_meta p
group by p.id
having sum(case when p.meta_key = 'listing_subtype' and p.meta_value = 'Seattle' 
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when p.meta_key = 'district' and p.meta_value = 'Breadview'
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when p.meta_key = 'price_current' and cast(p.meta_value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 800000
                then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Note:  This is untested so it might have a syntax error.

To get all information, join back the posts:

```
select p.*
from wp_posts p join
     (select p.id
      from wp_post_meta p
      group by p.id
      having sum(case when p.meta_key = 'listing_subtype' and p.meta_value = 'Seattle' 
                      then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when p.meta_key = 'district' and p.meta_value = 'Breadview'
                      then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
             sum(case when p.meta_key = 'price_current' and cast(p.meta_value as float) BETWEEN 0 AND 800000
                      then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    ) p2
    on p.id = p2.id
```

Comment: You forgot the table `wpostmeta` :)

Comment: Syntax error, I'm afraid.

Comment: @dcolumbus . . . I fixed the obvious syntax errors.